# Adjustbox inside figure environment

Tags: adjustbox

I am trying to use the `adjustbox` package. When I use the `adjustbox` command inside a `\ffigbox` (`floatrow` package) it works fine. Now I wanted to use it inside a figure environment. Therfore I used the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{\include{images/plot/associativity}}
%\include{images/plot/associativity}
\caption{Associativity compared to execution time}\label{fig:intro:associativity}
\floatfoot{Matrix multiplication on the \emph{leon3}, normalized by longest execution time. Lower is better. There is no optimal solution across all problem sizes}
\end{figure}
```

Latex gives me the following error if I use the `\adjustbox` line, and works fine if I use the pure include:

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup \end{figure}

Since my MWE turned out to actually contian an error, but I think the parantheses in this `adjustbox` line are balanced, I have an issue, I am tryuing to build a new (non working) M<strike>W</strike>E

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}      
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{asso.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{\include{asso}}
%\include{asso}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have an extra `}`, just like the error says in the `\adjustbox` line. End it with two `}}` rather than `}}}`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typing error

Comment: give me a sec guzs, I checked for the brace in my main document quite a few times and thought i had it right. I am just checking if I made a mistake putting together the mwe, or I have an actual problem.

Comment: @egreg I am trying to get a proper MWE, but either I am to tired or I have the wrong MWE.

Comment: Using `\include` inside `\adjustbox` is asking for troubles. Use `\include` only for big chunks like chapters (and it's not so useful as it was in the past); it should be `\input`.

Comment: @egreg: thanks for your eagle eye, it fixed it. I went on to learn about [include vs input](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/19326).

Comment: @ted: Yes, `\include` is the problem, since it issues a `\clearpage`... Does using `\input` solve your problem?

Comment: @Werner: yes it does (see comment just above yours).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\include` is the wrong command to use; it should be reserved to big chunks of text, such as chapters. See [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/19326) for more information.